# BIRT - How to set password on generated pdf file?

Tags: birt, birt-emitter

How do I set a password on the generated `pdf` file programatically? The password comes from the data source (xml field).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `pdf`-File is generated from a `birt-emitter`. So you need to write an extension to an existing (open) PDF-Emitter or wirte a complete new PDF-Emitter, as I think this feature is not implemented in the default PDF-Emitter.